# extract background color with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose we set background on an element as following:

1. background: green
2. background: url("big_green.png")
3. background: green url("big_green") no-repat
4. background: url("big_green") green no-repeat

What I want is to extract the background-color value, not the value in the url().

Comment: background:\s?\"(?<colour>\w*)\"

Comment: Can't you use `element.style.backgroundColor`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion about the question, I have modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
 (?:background:\s")(.+)(?:")
```

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nW9hR9)**

**Explanation :**
`(?:background:\s")`    Non-capturing group

`background:` matches the characters background: literally (case sensitive)

`\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

`"` matches the character `"` literally

1st Capturing group `(.+)`

`.+` matches any character (except newline)

Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`(?:")` Non-capturing group

`"` matches the character `"` literally

[image]

Comment: It seems not work for me. It will also extract "green" in the url().

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it still not what I want. I have clearified the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for

```
background:\s"(.+)"
```

This way you suppose there can be only a whitespace (`\s`) and a `"` after the `background`. It won't match if `url` comes after `background` and you don't need any lookaheads for this.

[Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uD4mX6)

**EDIT**
According to your third and fourth example the regex above obviously won't work.

```
background:\s(?:"(.+)"|(?!url)(\w+)|url\(.+\) (.+?)\s)
```

This one will match all your example cases.

[Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xL5hH7)

Explanation:

```
background:\s  #matches "background: " literally
(?:            #start of non-capturing group
      "(.+)"   #matches characters enclodes by "" (Example 1)
    |          #OR
      (?!url)  #negative lookahead: if "url" comes afterwards, this isn't a match
      (\w+)    #matches mupltiple characters (Example 3)
    |          #OR
      url\(    #matches "url(" literally
      .+       #matches multiple characters
      \)       #matches ") " literally
      (.+?)\s  #matches multiple characters until the next whitespace (Example 4)
)              #end of non-capturing group
```

Comment: it can't fit the third case